# New Dell G3-3579 Reaching 104 Celsius in 10 Minutes From Gaming - Tips?

Tags: laptop, ssd, cooling, gaming

A year ago I purchased a Dell G3-3579-BLKPUS. It had a problem and was returned with a new SSHD, a Firecuda.
This machine has an Intel i5-8300H and a GTX 1050 TI. The game is on a recently purchased 256GB Kingston **SSD** - the laptop also has an insanely slow 1 TB Firecuda SSHD 5400RPM with a max speed of 16 MB/s.

Recently I have begun to actually use it for gaming. I decided to try the game Escape from Tarkov. I launched the game, and within a few minutes my laptop became super slow. Task Manager showed 96% CPU and 75% GPU on just the Title Screen without anything occurring. Tarkov was using 50% of the FireCuda **SSHD**. I started smelling burning after 10 more minutes of being on main menu so I checked HWiNFO and it showed 104C on the CPU, so I exited.

I'm not sure what to do to help my laptop run the game. How can I help my laptop stay cool while playing this game? And, if possible, does anyone know if 104C for about 4 minutes causes damage? Thank you in advance.

Comment: That processor has a TJUNCTION of 100, so 104c is not great.  That said, it is an Intel CPU and it will underclock itself to protect itself from damage, so chances are the CPU itself is OK.  If nothing stopped working it is quite probable your system is not damaged - but its impossible to say for sure.

Comment: Thank you for the valuable information - know any good ways to test for CPU damage within the OS itself, or is it just benching and seeing if that gives bsods/artifacting/etc?

Comment: If you have damage from a burning smell it probably won't be the CPU. Its more likely to be a blown/melted cap or wire.  I don't know of a complete way to test the CPU offhand. Stress/prime95 are often bandied around.